# Как в корзине для определенной кагегории товаров изменить формулу расчета итоговой суммы?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, корзина

Всем привет. Помогите новичку пожалуйста. Я только осваиваю wp и wc. В магазине есть 2 категории товаров. Пиво и закуски. У пива цена идет за 1 литр. У закусок цена идёт за 50 грамм. Для закусок шаг количества в инпуте корзины идёт 50 грамм (50,100,150 и т.д.), но когда цена за 50 грамм есть 20грн. например, то при выборе в инпуте 200 грамм должна отображаться цена 80 грн., а по факту получается 20грн.*200=4000 грн.

Вопрос  1. Можно ли изменить формулу расчета в корзине для категории snack. Получается нужно чтобы итог в строке делился на 50. [4000/50=80грн.](если брать пример выше).

Вопрос 2. Может есть другой выход? Задать для категории snack цену 20 грн за 50грамм  и после этого все четко будет считаться когда мы будем выбирать 50,100,150,200 и т.д.?????

Фото прилагается чтобы было более понятно :)
За ранее всем спасибо за помощь!!! 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам уже на 2 вопроса ответили. От вас ни ответа, ни привета. Думаете, найдутся желающие продолжать?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, что не поблагодарил вас. Сейчас куча проблем и забот, то ребёнок болел то жена то ещё что-то. Вы помогли мне решить задачу с шагом в 50 в инпуте в корзине. Спасибо вам большое! По первому вопросу я нашёл решение такое. В товар добавил метабокс. В него внес необходимый тест и вывел его там где было нужно! Спасибо ещё раз за помощь!